# How to best position the keyword combination "[keyword] near me" for local SEO and organic search?

Tags: seo, google-search, website-design, local-seo, google-local-search

I am involved in the digital marketing efforts for a business that aims to increase its local visibility in organic search results. Our target keyword combination is "[keyword] near me", where "keyword" refers to a specific service or product the business offers.

I understand that SEO, particularly local and organic SEO, involves many variables such as keyword usage, link building, mobile compatibility, and local citations among others. However, I am interested in understanding more specific strategies and tactics that we could employ.

How can we optimize our website and content to target users who are geographically close to our business and searching for "[keyword] near me"?

What strategies are recommended for increasing our visibility in organic search results for "[keyword] near me"?

Are there specific tools or techniques that can help us measure our current performance in local SEO and the effectiveness of the changes we implement?

I would greatly appreciate any insights on this topic. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice for the getting the most out of "[keyword] near me" is the following: create pages dedicated to cities where you offer your service, but without being spammy. You don't want 50 pages, all similar, with just the city name being different. Spend time to differentiate them and group them (if it makes sense, based on demand or search volume). And don't roll out all pages at once. SEO shouldn't be seen as a lonely tactic, but integrated with the business and part of the brand growth.

Just bear in mind that using the actual keyword "near me" in meta titles or in any other part of the content is not really a best practice. Google uses it to understand the user's intent and serve results that are near them.

Oh, and look at the competition, even in other states. You will identify websites that do it properly and you can get inspiration from them (if they rank high, Google likes them for a reason).

Local SEO is the sum of all efforts to try to rank in a specific area and sometimes it's harder to measure it all (maybe someone is doing a brand search and the map result pops up). Google My Business should indeed be used and fully optimized.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the best solutions to achieve your goal is to optimize your content for the potential to get your products or services in SERPs as featured snippets. Check out Google's comments about **[Our latest quality improvements to featured snippets](https://blog.google/products/search/information-literacy/)**:

> We design our ranking systems to surface relevant information from the
> most reliable sources available – sources that demonstrate expertise,
> authoritativeness and trustworthiness.

and

> Featured snippets are the descriptive box at the top of the page that
> prominently highlights a piece of information from a result and the
> source, in response to your query. They’re helpful both for people
> searching on Google, and for web publishers, as featured snippets
> drive traffic to sites.

In my opinion here, important for a business that wants to have a high position in the SERP for the query "Product near me" is the phrase that Google algorithms bring to the surface from the ***most trustworthy sources***. In turn, this leads us to the idea of creating content entities, which are uniquely identifiable objects associated with other website content entities.

Any business can be represented as a uniquely identifiable entity (including local SEO) that is associated with entities that represent the product or service offered by that business.

Thus, when searching for "Product near me", Google determines the current location of the user and looks for relevant information in its index.

If the content of your website is considered by Google to be content from a trusted source and can uniquely identify the business, its location (for services, possibly including the service area), and uniquely identify each product or service offered by the business, then it is highly likely to receive these entities in the form of a featured snippet or at least in the SERP top. This is a very achievable goal of online branding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only local search results, the best choice is to use Google My Business. But if you want search results "near me" for your website, you can do like I do in my country and create pages with the local name area that you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks. Besides creating pages with the local name area, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From my **past experience** here are some tips you can follow:

1. Name your page **link** keyword-wise or location-wise. Example: plumber-in-newyork.
2. You can put the "keyword + near me" type of keyword in the **website meta**.
3. Use **Google Maps** in your page. Make sure you are putting the targeted location.
4. Content should be SEO friendly with keyword
5. Optimize your google my business

This is one of my client's website results. Local business in Germany:
[image]